# NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/stax2/ri/Stax2WriterAdapter using jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have a problem using `jackson` when I try to convert `json` to `XML` - full [documentation](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/convert-json-to-xml/) .

My converting function -

```
public org.w3c.dom.Element jsonToXml(JsonNode json) throws JsonProcessingException, ParserConfigurationException{
        org.w3c.dom.Element toReturn = null;
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        String jsonString = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(json.toString());
        javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory b = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = b.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.newDocument(); 
        toReturn = doc.createElement(jsonString); 
        //return Element
        return toReturn;
    }
```

And getting this error - `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/stax2/ri/Stax2WriterAdapter`, I do not any reference to `Stax2WriterAdapter` in my class.

Full error log -

`com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet GtoQuotesServlets in application MatafServiceServletsEAR. Exception created : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/stax2/ri/Stax2WriterAdapter at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator.<init>(ToXmlGenerator.java:156) at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory.createGenerator(XmlFactory.java:366) at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory.createGenerator(XmlFactory.java:27) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2927) at mataf.service.servlets.GtoQuotesServlets.jsonToXml(GtoQuotesServlets.java:333) at mataf.service.servlets.GtoQuotesServlets.writeTumlugimToLog(GtoQuotesServlets.java:177) at mataf.service.servlets.GtoQuotesServlets.doPost(GtoQuotesServlets.java:143) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:944) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3954) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191) at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453) at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515) at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306) at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84) at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1819) at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1660)`

Comment: It is mostly because you dont have the dependency required to use that library. Can you check that. If you have used maven or gradle for dependency management then it should have solved your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not referencing `Stax2WriterAdapter` but [`ToXmlGenerator`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/ser/ToXmlGenerator.java) is.
You need to add the jar that contains this class. 
According to [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api/4.0.0) last version of that jar would be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

BTW you're referencing pretty old library and tutorial. I suggest looking at something [more recent](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization).